# How to solve attenuation caused by filter coefficient quantization in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

Before quantization of filter coefficient, it behaves well, but after quantization the amplitude drops to 0.52186, which is expected to be 1000(fig.1). But according to the amplitude response in filterDesigner(fig.2). The 200Hz wave shouldn't decrease so much after filtering. Could someone tell me why the abnormal attenuation happens? Why is it 0.52186?

Fig.1 effect of filter

[image: Fig.1 effect of filter]

Fig.2 amplitude response

[image: Fig.2 amplitude response]

```
N = 2000;
f0=200;
f1=800;
fs=2000;
n=1:N;
y =1000*sin(2*pi*f0.*n/fs)+500*sin(2*pi*f1.*n/fs);
Hd = filter_below500Hz;
d = filter(Hd,y);
figure(2)
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(y);
title({['y，before filtering']});
subplot(2,1,2)
plot(d);
title({['d，after filtering']});
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. First of all IMHO I would consider this rather signal processing question and not a programming question. I recommend to ask those questions here: [DSP.SE](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/). When designing a filter you have normally certain specifications, e.g. stopband  or passband attenuation. You should choose your quantization in that way that this specification still hold. Have a look on the frequency response of the quantized coefficients. Right now your given example, does not allow to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Have a look also at this matlab example [optimized-fixed-point-fir-filters](https://de.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ug/optimized-fixed-point-fir-filters.html)

Comment: Thank you ! I'll ramove this question there !